# (Neo4j 3.5) Executing query with two parts and the second one consists on a group of matches where at least one needs to be fulfilled

Tags: neo4j, cypher

we are trying to run a cypher query but we are not able to get the results we want.

It is important to note that we cannot make this work with subqueries because we are using Neo4j 3.5 and in this version, they are still not available.

The problem is that we have two parts for a query, the first one will fix the variables for the second part, and the second part consists of multiple matches, and it has to get the results of the previous query and if at least one of the matches return a result for a row, this row is not filtered out, else if none return result it is discarded.

More specifically, the query we are trying to run is similar to the following one:

```
//First part of the query where we want to fix variables with the match and where
MATCH (u:User)-[:ASSIGNED_TO]->(t:Task)-[:PENDING]->(ob:Object)<-[:HAS_OPEN_OBJECT]-(do:DataObject)<-[:ASOCIATED]-(:Module)-[:CAN_LIST]->(view:WidgetObject)
                        WHERE u.uid = 'user_uid' 
                        AND view.uid = 'view_uid' 
                        AND view.object_name = do.object_type
                        with do, t, ob

// In this second part of the query we want to maintain the variables of the previous part and if at least one matches the value should be returned
// we have tried with UNION but we will need pagination, but even with union it's not working 
MATCH (ac:Action)<-[:ASOCIATED]-(t)-[rel:COMPLETED|PENDING]->(ob)<-[:HAS_OPEN_OBJECT|HAS_CLOSED_OBJECT]-(do)
                WHERE ac.name CONTAINS 'body'
                WITH COLLECT({data_object_uid: do.uid}) as act_filter
MATCH (c:Comment)<-[:COMMENTED]-(t)-[rel:COMPLETED|PENDING]->(ob)<-[:HAS_OPEN_OBJECT|HAS_CLOSED_OBJECT]-(do)
                WHERE c.body CONTAINS 'body'
                WITH act_filter  + COLLECT({data_object_uid: do.uid}) as comment_filter
MATCH (at:Attachment)<-[:HAS_ATTACHMENT]-(t)-[rel:COMPLETED|PENDING]->(ob)<-[:HAS_OPEN_OBJECT|HAS_CLOSED_OBJECT]-(do)
                WHERE at.name CONTAINS 'body'
                WITH comment_filter + COLLECT({data_object_uid: do.uid}) as attachment_filter
                UNWIND attachment_filter as row
                return row.data_object_uid
```

We are not sure if in the second part, the second and third matches are maintaining the same subset of results coming from the first part of the query.

A funny behavior we have found is that if we remove the last match we are getting results but if we add it, we are not getting any results. We do not understand this behavior because if the second match is returning results and they are stored in a variable after a collect, appending this to the next collected results should return something.

For example, if the second match returns as comment_filter `[{data_object_uid: "343dienmd3-dasd"}]` and the third match is not returning anything, after the concatenation in the `WITH` clause it should return the same thing, but the result is empty.

We need some light here, we don't know if we are close and we are making a stupid mistake or we are getting all wrong and we need to change the approach completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not know which of the three matches in the second part will yield results, I would try something along the lines below:

NOTE I used ASSOCIATED instead of ASOCIATED

```
MATCH (n)<-[:ASSOCIATED|COMMENTED|HAS_ATTACHMENT]-(t)-[rel:COMPLETED|PENDING]->(ob)<-[:HAS_OPEN_OBJECT|HAS_CLOSED_OBJECT]-(do)
WHERE 
      (n:Action AND n.name CONTAINS 'body')
      OR
      (n:Comment AND n.body CONTAINS 'body')
      OR 
      (n:Attachment AND n.name CONTAINS 'body')
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT {data_object_uid: do.uid})
```